# BufferedReader.readline() not working when chatting on socket

Tags: java, sockets, bufferedreader

I'm using sockets to chat as part of a large application, however so you can read it easier i have made 2 classes that show the problem. I have a server and a client, the server opens a socket and waits for a client to connect once connected it sends them a welcome message. On the client side they display the welcome message then enter a loop to write to the PrintWriter. On the server side it will now enter a loop that constantly displays text from the bufferedReader however nothing is printing out, not sure if i'm being stupid but think it needs a fresh pair of eyes, Thanks.

```
public class Server {

public static boolean running = true;
public static PrintWriter out;
public static BufferedReader in;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ServerSocket s = new ServerSocket(1932);
    while (true) {
        Socket cs = s.accept();
        out = new PrintWriter(cs.getOutputStream(), true);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(cs.getInputStream()));
        out.println("Welcome");
        out.flush();
        while (running == true) {
            String input = in.readLine();
            if (input.equals("QUIT")) {
                System.out.println("theyve gone :( ");
                cs.close();
                running = false;
            } else {
                System.out.println(input);
            }

          }

       }
    }
}



public class Client {

public static boolean running = true;
public static PrintWriter out;
public static BufferedReader in;
public static Scanner scan;

public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException{

    Socket so = new Socket("localhost", 1932);
    out = new PrintWriter(so.getOutputStream());
    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(so.getInputStream()));
    System.out.println("TYPE QUIT TO LEAVE ");
    System.out.println(in.readLine());
    while(true){
        scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String message = scan.next();
        out.print(message);
        out.flush();


    }
  }  

}
```

Comment: readLine() reads until you write a newline.  If you don't write one it read until you close the connection or run out of memory.

Answer (score 3):

In the server, you're reading the next line:

```
String input = in.readLine();
```

So the server blocks until the end of line is reached (or the stream is closed).

And on the client, you  never send any end of line:

```
out.print(message);
```